# Android get wrong position (always the same wrong point) when app in background

Tags: android, background, localization

My Android app has to send position to the server periodically, every 10 seconds. 
It runs in a IntentService the code that starts the periodic localization in the smartphone; I use at the moment:

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, MYLOCATIONREQUEST, this, Looper.getMainLooper());
```

It works fine if the app is in foreground; when my app goes in background, the periodic localization continue to work, but after some time (around 2 minutes) the coordinates it gets are wrong: I'm sitted down at home with my smartphone, so I'm an in a fixed position (point A), and at the beginning the position is right, but after the 2 minutes the smartphone get a wrong fixed position (point B), that is always the same; I mean that if I do the same the day after, when the app goes in backround, after the 2 minutes it gets the same position B of the day before. In some case, less often, I noted it gets another point (point C), and also in this case it is fixed, that is it continue to get always point C.
When the app cames back in foregroung, after few seconds it gets again the right position (Point A).

To be noted that I put the log debug 'FAU_DEBUG' (see below) inside overriden method 'onLocationChanged()': also when in background, it is given regularly a position every 10 seconds.
Moreover I'm using at the moment always 'ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION' (FINE is not enabled in Android settings).

I noted also that:

- when my app is in foreground and the display goes off, after a couple of minutes it starts to get the wrong position B.
- when my app is in foreground, and I swhich to another app (for example to whastapp) and the display is on, it continues to get the right position A until the display is on; when the display goes off, then it starts to get the wrong position B

Summarising, when the app goes in background and the display goes off, it gets at the beginning the correct point A,  after 2 minutes it gets the wrong point B (and less often the wrong point C). When the app comes back in foreground it gets again the correct point A.

Below the log, where:

- point A is: Long _____12.4505882 -- Lat=41.8227214
- point B is: Long
  _____12.455792 -- Lat=41.8242919

You can see them in the log messages tagged as '*******FAU_DEBUG*******'.

I tried to understand what could be to cause the error; the only android message can say me something about that is 'com.google.android.location.ALARM_WAKEUP_LOCATOR elapsed', but only sometime it is present very often, also when the problem doesn't occurs.

Android smartphone has 6.0 (Marshmellow).

This is for me a big problem, because the main target of my app is to localize the smartphones, and of course normally the display is off and the app goes in background.

```
02-18 14:53:45.758 E: readlink('/proc/self/fd/44') failed: Permission denied [fd=44]
02-18 14:53:45.758 E: warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000053/n/arm64-v8a/libcronet.61.0.3163.140.so". Will use given name.
02-18 14:53:45.766 I: Cronet version: 61.0.3163.140, arch: aarch64
02-18 14:53:45.851 I: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 116052(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 92(4MB) LOS objects, 17% free, 55MB/67MB, paused 2.486ms total 215.096ms
02-18 14:53:45.918 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:53:45.919 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:53:45.991 I: addGeofences: geofencingRequest=GeofencingRequest[geofences=[Geofence[CIRCLE id:atn_geofence_request_id transitions:2 41.824292, 12.455792 20000m, resp=0s, dwell=-1ms, @77951352]], initialTrigger=2, tag=] intent=PendingIntent{d568a02: android.os.BinderProxy@e29e787}
02-18 14:53:45.993 I: Use last location to update newly added Geofences.
02-18 14:53:46.098 I: expired arrive. level:-1
02-18 14:53:46.098 I: during_ms:2003,period_ms:2000
02-18 14:53:46.098 I: count:184,rx_sum:1,tx_sum:2,rxBytes:85,during_ms:2003,rx_speed:42.43634548177733,tx_speed:69.39590614078881,rto:0.5
02-18 14:53:46.921 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:53:46.921 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:53:47.110 I: update:rxPkts:0,txPkts:0,rxBytes:0,txBytes:0
02-18 14:53:47.111 I: start expired. level:-1
02-18 14:53:47.111 I: gettimer:interval=2000
02-18 14:53:47.117 W: WAKEUP alarm trigger action = com.google.android.location.ALARM_WAKEUP_LOCATOR elapsed = 63252514

                      [ 02-18 14:53:47.142 29309:29309 W/         ]
                      Classe ' *******FAU_DEBUG*******  --- 14:53:47:140 --- LocationManager' -|||- 'onLocationChanged()' -|||- ****************************:   **Long _____12.4505882 -- Lat=41.8227214** -- Datetime=Sun Feb 18 14:53:47 GMT+01:00 2018____          -|||- Nome Thread (che invoca il Log)='main' 


                      [ 02-18 14:53:47.144 29309:29309 W/         ]
                      Classe ' *******FAU_DEBUG*******  --- 14:53:47:143 --- LocationManager' -|||- 'onLocationChanged()' -|||- ****************************:   MYLOCATION_Arg _____Location[fused 42******,12****** acc=317 et=+17h34m7s518ms]____          -|||- Nome Thread (che invoca il Log)='main' 
02-18 14:53:47.924 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:53:47.924 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:53:48.927 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:53:48.927 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:53:49.043 E: [charger_ic] temp_new :32  temp_old :31
02-18 14:53:49.043 E: Report temperature: [charger_ic] temp :32  report_threshold:1
02-18 14:53:49.116 I: update:rxPkts:0,txPkts:0,rxBytes:0,txBytes:0
02-18 14:53:49.116 I: start expired. level:-1
02-18 14:53:49.116 I: gettimer:interval=2000
02-18 14:53:49.527 I: NotificationGuideService:handle MSG_ACTIVIY_FOREGROUND, uid:10058

02-18 14:53:49.560 I:  uid:10151 pid:-2 flags:536870922 tag:WindowManager wakeup time:222333
02-18 14:53:49.582 I: NotificationGuideService:handle MSG_ACTIVIY_FOREGROUND, uid:10151                      

02-18 14:53:49.689 W: removeNotificationEntry for unknown key: 0|com.fpricoco.etip|101|null|10151
02-18 14:53:49.717 I: alloc w[1080] h[1920] format[1] usage[2816]
02-18 14:53:49.721 I: alloc succ handle[0x55941194f0] stride[1120]
02-18 14:53:49.721 I: alloc w[1080] h[1920] format[1] usage[2816]
02-18 14:53:49.728 I: alloc succ handle[0x5594013cd0] stride[1120]
02-18 14:53:49.728 I: alloc w[1080] h[1920] format[1] usage[2816]
02-18 14:53:49.733 I: alloc succ handle[0x559402d280] stride[1120]
02-18 14:53:49.753 I: Displayed com.fpricoco.etip/.Activities.BaseActivity: +174ms (total +186ms)
02-18 14:53:49.928 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:53:49.928 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:53:50.191 W: HwNotification updateNotifications size is zero
 02-18 14:53:50.803 I: addNotification notification pkgName=com.fpricoco.etip,isOngoing=true,isCleanable=false
02-18 14:53:50.883 I: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
02-18 14:53:50.884 I: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
02-18 14:53:50.884 I: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
02-18 14:53:51.121 I: update:rxPkts:0,txPkts:0,rxBytes:0,txBytes:0
02-18 14:53:51.122 I: start expired. level:-1
02-18 14:53:51.122 I: gettimer:interval=2000
02-18 14:53:51.180 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:53:51.180 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:53:51.305 W: HwNotification updateNotifications size is zero
02-18 14:53:51.769 E: updateConfiguration freq=2427 BSSID=90:35:6e:e7:a2:88 RSSI=-68 "Vodafone-FAU"WPA_PSK
02-18 14:53:51.780 I: spd good count:0, add sc:0.0, rate:1.0
02-18 14:53:51.781 I: current mHighDataFlowRate = 1.0
02-18 14:53:51.781 I: POta txb txg rxg:0, 2, 0. Lr =0% Totpkt=2
02-18 14:53:51.782 I: ######### CMD_QUERY_PKTS ########
02-18 14:53:51.783 I: postEventFromNative: msg=100,arg1=0,arg2=9
02-18 14:53:51.783 W: poll before: g_monitor_fd =131
02-18 14:53:51.783 I: rtt=400,tcp_tx_pkts=75574,tcp_rx_pkts=140276
02-18 14:53:51.784 I: PTcp RTT:0, rtt pkt=0, tcp_rx=1, tcp_tx=2, tcp_reTran=0, rtRate=0
02-18 14:53:51.784 I: rs ota tcp lr rttvb bad: false, false, false, false, false; rsth:-75
02-18 14:53:51.785 I:  pkt chk not bad, reset sc to 0.
02-18 14:53:51.794 I: QOS_level:5(5),wifi-link;use signalLvl:5;RAT:4G
02-18 14:53:52.112 I: expired arrive. level:-1
02-18 14:53:52.112 I: during_ms:2005,period_ms:2000
02-18 14:53:52.112 I: count:187,rx_sum:0,tx_sum:0,rxBytes:0,during_ms:2005,rx_speed:0.0,tx_speed:0.0,rto:0.0
02-18 14:53:52.146 W: WAKEUP alarm trigger action = com.google.android.location.ALARM_WAKEUP_LOCATOR elapsed = 63257542
02-18 14:53:52.173 W: shouldBlockLocation running ...
02-18 14:53:52.173 I: shouldBlockLocation  ret:false
02-18 14:53:52.180 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:53:52.180 W: shouldBlockLocation running ...
02-18 14:53:52.181 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:53:52.181 I: shouldBlockLocation  ret:false


                02-18 14:53:53.125 I: update:rxPkts:3,txPkts:3,rxBytes:174,txBytes:177
02-18 14:53:53.125 I: start expired. level:-1
02-18 14:53:53.126 I: gettimer:interval=2000
02-18 14:53:53.183 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:53:53.183 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:53:53.894 I: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
02-18 14:53:54.186 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:53:54.186 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:53:54.682 I: action:android.os.action.POWER_SAVE_TEMP_WHITELIST_CHANGED, mPermissionType:0
02-18 14:53:55.072 I: action:com.google.android.gms.gcm.ACTION_SCHEDULE, mPermissionType:0
02-18 14:53:55.129 I: update:rxPkts:0,txPkts:0,rxBytes:0,txBytes:0
02-18 14:53:55.129 I: start expired. level:-1
02-18 14:53:55.129 I: gettimer:interval=2000
02-18 14:53:55.186 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:53:55.187 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:53:56.442 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:53:56.442 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:53:57.135 I: update:rxPkts:0,txPkts:0,rxBytes:0,txBytes:0
02-18 14:53:57.135 I: start expired. level:-1
02-18 14:53:57.135 I: gettimer:interval=2000
02-18 14:53:57.162 W: WAKEUP alarm trigger action = com.google.android.location.ALARM_WAKEUP_LOCATOR elapsed = 63262559

                      [ 02-18 14:53:57.202 29309:29309 W/         ]
                      Classe ' *******FAU_DEBUG*******  --- 14:53:57:201 --- LocationManager' -|||- 'onLocationChanged()' -|||- ****************************:   Long _____12.4505882 -- Lat=41.8227214 -- Datetime=Sun Feb 18 14:53:57 GMT+01:00 2018____          -|||- Nome Thread (che invoca il Log)='main' 


                      [ 02-18 14:53:57.205 29309:29309 W/         ]
                      Classe ' *******FAU_DEBUG*******  --- 14:53:57:204 --- LocationManager' -|||- 'onLocationChanged()' -|||- ****************************:   MYLOCATION_Arg _____Location[fused 42******,12****** acc=328 et=+17h34m17s566ms]____          -|||- Nome Thread (che invoca il Log)='main' 
02-18 14:53:57.224 I: Successfully inserted 1 locations
02-18 14:53:57.324 E: getTempInfo error: null, 0
02-18 14:53:57.324 E: getTempInfo error: null, 0
02-18 14:53:57.324 E: getTempInfo error: null, 0
02-18 14:53:57.324 E: getTempInfo error: null, 0
02-18 14:53:57.324 E: getTempInfo error: null, 0
02-18 14:53:57.340 E: getTempInfo error: null, 0
02-18 14:53:57.340 E: getTempInfo error: null, 0
02-18 14:53:57.340 E: getTempInfo error: null, 0
02-18 14:53:57.340 E: getTempInfo error: null, 0
02-18 14:53:57.340 E: getTempInfo error: null, 0
02-18 14:53:57.347 W: writeLogFile > 10240 ,tagTempAlarm
02-18 14:53:57.445 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:53:57.446 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:53:58.129 I: expired arrive. level:-1
02-18 14:53:58.129 I: during_ms:2006,period_ms:2000
02-18 14:53:58.130 I: count:190,rx_sum:0,tx_sum:0,rxBytes:0,during_ms:2006,rx_speed:0.0,tx_speed:0.0,rto:0.0
02-18 14:53:58.449 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:53:58.449 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:53:59.141 I: update:rxPkts:0,txPkts:0,rxBytes:0,txBytes:0
02-18 14:53:59.141 I: start expired. level:-1
02-18 14:53:59.141 I: gettimer:interval=2000
02-18 14:53:59.454 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:53:59.454 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:53:59.783 E: updateConfiguration freq=2427 BSSID=90:35:6e:e7:a2:88 RSSI=-68 "Vodafone-FAU"WPA_PSK
02-18 14:53:59.792 I: spd good count:0, add sc:0.0, rate:1.0
02-18 14:53:59.793 I: current mHighDataFlowRate = 1.0
02-18 14:53:59.794 I: POta txb txg rxg:0, 5, 0. Lr =0% Totpkt=5
02-18 14:53:59.795 I: ######### CMD_QUERY_PKTS ########
02-18 14:53:59.795 I: postEventFromNative: msg=100,arg1=0,arg2=9
02-18 14:53:59.796 W: poll before: g_monitor_fd =131
02-18 14:53:59.796 I: rtt=800,tcp_tx_pkts=75577,tcp_rx_pkts=140279
02-18 14:53:59.798 I: PTcp RTT:0, rtt pkt=0, tcp_rx=3, tcp_tx=3, tcp_reTran=0, rtRate=0
02-18 14:53:59.799 I: rs ota tcp lr rttvb bad: false, false, false, false, false; rsth:-75
02-18 14:53:59.799 I:  pkt chk not bad, reset sc to 0.
02-18 14:53:59.805 I: QOS_level:5(5),wifi-link;use signalLvl:5;RAT:4G
02-18 14:54:00.456 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:54:00.456 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:54:00.829 I: NotificationGuideService:handle MSG_ACTIVIY_FOREGROUND, uid:10058
02-18 14:54:00.863 I:  uid:10151 pid:-2 flags:536870922 tag:WindowManager wakeup time:233482
02-18 14:54:00.880 I: NotificationGuideService:handle MSG_ACTIVIY_FOREGROUND, uid:10151
02-18 14:54:00.978 W: removeNotificationEntry for unknown key: 0|com.fpricoco.etip|101|null|10151
02-18 14:54:01.003 I: alloc w[1080] h[1920] format[1] usage[2816]
02-18 14:54:01.007 I: alloc succ handle[0x559402d280] stride[1120]
02-18 14:54:01.008 I: alloc w[1080] h[1920] format[1] usage[2816]
02-18 14:54:01.015 I: alloc succ handle[0x5594013cd0] stride[1120]
02-18 14:54:01.015 I: alloc w[1080] h[1920] format[1] usage[2816]
02-18 14:54:01.021 I: alloc succ handle[0x55941194f0] stride[1120]
02-18 14:54:01.038 I: Displayed com.fpricoco.etip/.Activities.BaseActivity: +161ms (total +174ms)
02-18 14:54:01.143 I: update:rxPkts:0,txPkts:0,rxBytes:0,txBytes:0
02-18 14:54:01.143 I: start expired. level:-1
02-18 14:54:01.143 I: gettimer:interval=2000
02-18 14:54:01.479 W: HwNotification updateNotifications size is zero
02-18 14:54:01.711 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:54:01.711 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
                      02-18 14:54:02.090 I: addNotification notification pkgName=com.fpricoco.etip,isOngoing=true,isCleanable=false
02-18 14:54:02.168 I: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
02-18 14:54:02.170 I: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
02-18 14:54:02.171 I: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
02-18 14:54:02.206 W: WAKEUP alarm trigger action = com.google.android.location.ALARM_WAKEUP_LOCATOR elapsed = 63267604
02-18 14:54:02.209 I: receiver action = android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
02-18 14:54:02.212 I: Model  onReceive intent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.TIME_TICK flg=0x50000014 (has extras) }
02-18 14:54:02.212 I: Model  onReceive user=UserHandle{0}
02-18 14:54:02.218 I: onTimeChanged
02-18 14:54:02.224 I: CityTimeView CityTimeView mCurrentViewMode = 42001
02-18 14:54:02.225 W: onWeatherChange : displayInfo is null!
02-18 14:54:02.225 I: WidgetUtils trasnslateImageResource, resId is 2130837801 isLight =false
02-18 14:54:02.226 I: WidgetUtils trasnslateImageResource, resId is 2130837801 isLight =false
02-18 14:54:02.226 I: WidgetUtils trasnslateImageResource, resId is 2130837803 isLight =false
02-18 14:54:02.232 W: shouldBlockLocation running ...
02-18 14:54:02.233 I: shouldBlockLocation  ret:false
02-18 14:54:02.240 W: shouldBlockLocation running ...
02-18 14:54:02.240 I: shouldBlockLocation  ret:false
02-18 14:54:02.251 I: CityTimeFormatView CityTimeFormatView setTimeFormat is24Hour=true,timeFormat=
02-18 14:54:02.591 W: HwNotification updateNotifications size is zero
02-18 14:54:02.713 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:54:02.714 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:54:03.147 I: update:rxPkts:0,txPkts:0,rxBytes:0,txBytes:0
02-18 14:54:03.147 I: start expired. level:-1
02-18 14:54:03.147 I: gettimer:interval=2000
02-18 14:54:03.716 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:54:03.716 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:54:04.143 I: expired arrive. level:-1
02-18 14:54:04.143 I: during_ms:2004,period_ms:2000
02-18 14:54:04.143 I: count:193,rx_sum:0,tx_sum:0,rxBytes:0,during_ms:2004,rx_speed:0.0,tx_speed:0.0,rto:0.0
02-18 14:54:04.719 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:54:04.719 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:54:04.857 I: onSignal: mSubId=0,currDataSubID=0
02-18 14:54:04.857 I: received cell-signal:5
02-18 14:54:04.857 I: action:android.intent.action.SIG_STR, mPermissionType:0
02-18 14:54:04.867 I: subId:0 phoneType:1 networktype:13 targetClass:3 masterLevel:4 slaveLevel:-1
02-18 14:54:05.150 I: update:rxPkts:0,txPkts:0,rxBytes:0,txBytes:0
02-18 14:54:05.151 I: start expired. level:-1
02-18 14:54:05.151 I: gettimer:interval=2000
02-18 14:54:05.177 I: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
02-18 14:54:05.722 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:54:05.722 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:54:06.978 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:54:06.978 I: Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...
02-18 14:54:07.156 I: update:rxPkts:0,txPkts:0,rxBytes:0,txBytes:0
02-18 14:54:07.156 I: start expired. level:-1
02-18 14:54:07.156 I: gettimer:interval=2000
02-18 14:54:07.230 W: WAKEUP alarm trigger action = com.google.android.location.ALARM_WAKEUP_LOCATOR elapsed = 63272627

                      [ 02-18 14:54:07.250 29309:29309 W/         ]
                      Classe ' *******FAU_DEBUG*******  --- 14:54:07:249 --- LocationManager' -|||- 'onLocationChanged()' -|||- ****************************:   Long _____12.455792 -- Lat=41.8242919 -- Datetime=Sun Feb 18 14:54:07 GMT+01:00 2018____          -|||- Nome Thread (che invoca il Log)='main' 


                      [ 02-18 14:54:07.252 29309:29309 W/         ]
                      Classe ' *******FAU_DEBUG*******  --- 14:54:07:251 --- LocationManager' -|||- 'onLocationChanged()' -|||- ****************************:   MYLOCATION_Arg _____Location[fused 42******,12****** acc=700 et=+17h34m27s628ms]____          -|||- Nome Thread (che invoca il Log)='main' 
02-18 14:54:07.788 E: updateConfiguration freq=2427 BSSID=90:35:6e:e7:a2:88 RSSI=-67 "Vodafone-FAU"WPA_PSK
02-18 14:54:07.798 I: spd good count:0, add sc:0.0, rate:1.0
02-18 14:54:07.798 I: current mHighDataFlowRate = 1.0
02-18 14:54:07.798 I: POta txb txg rxg:0, 2, 0. Lr =0% Totpkt=2
02-18 14:54:07.798 I: ######### CMD_QUERY_PKTS ########
02-18 14:54:07.799 I: postEventFromNative: msg=100,arg1=0,arg2=9
02-18 14:54:07.799 W: poll before: g_monitor_fd =131
02-18 14:54:07.799 I: action:android.net.conn.DATA_ACTIVITY_CHANGE, mPermissionType:0
02-18 14:54:07.799 I: rtt=800,tcp_tx_pkts=75577,tcp_rx_pkts=140279
02-18 14:54:07.801 I: PTcp RTT:0, rtt pkt=0, tcp_rx=0, tcp_tx=0, tcp_reTran=0, rtRate=0
02-18 14:54:07.802 I: rs ota tcp lr rttvb bad: false, false, false, false, false; rsth:-75
02-18 14:54:07.802 I:  pkt chk not bad, reset sc to 0.
02-18 14:54:07.806 I: QOS_level:5(5),wifi-link;use signalLvl:5;RAT:4G
```

Comment: My assumption would be that when your app is backgrounded the location service isn't refreshing as often. Also I'd assume that when your app is foregrounded it'll use `FINE_LOCATION` and when backgrounded will use `COARSE_LOCATION`.

Comment: Try computing the distance between the FG value (assume as truth) and BG value and the deviation will most likely bear out @jack 's statement (celltower/wifi vs satellite).

Comment: Hi, I re-edited the queston to reply to your comments adding "To be noted that I put the log debug 'FAU_DEBUG' (see below) inside overriden method 'onLocationChanged()': also when in background, it is given regularly a position every 10 seconds. Moreover I'm using at the moment always 'ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION' (FINE is not enabled in Android settings). " .   So it cannot be the difference between celltower/wifi vs satellite. Moreover it sounds me strange that wrong point is always in the same point B... If it was due to less precision, it should be in different wrong points....

Comment: 2 minutes with the screen on or left apart with the screen off ?

Comment: Hi, I re-edited the question in order to reply to your comment, writing (you can also see above):  I noted also that:

 ---   when my app is in foreground and the display goes off, after a couple of minutes it starts to get the wrong position B.
   ---   when my app is in foreground, and I swhich to another app (for example to whastapp) and the display is on, it continues to get the right position A until the display is on; when the display goes off, then it starts to get the wrong position B

Comment: Try logging the provider in both cases : location.getProvider();

Comment: @Andy  --- If I understood correctly your point, I tried also using ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, that is GPS. ----  But nothing changed: it continues to get a wrong position after some time when my app goes in BG and the display goes off.

Comment: I was just thinking that when in BG and display goes off that a power-saving mode is entered which may override whichever location preference you specify - so I suggested logging (debug) the provider (using the location's getProvider()) when you get a location fix to see if it is changing - just informational.

Comment: @Andy  I checked again: getproviders() and it gives back always "fused" in both right and wrong position. Also previously you could see it seeing the log debug 'FAU_DEBUG', lookink at  "Location[fused 42***** ...."